# Force a style change in RadioButtonGroup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a RadioButtonGroup whos css class is 'radio' from Bootstrap.

It causes a table attribute called border collapse that I do not want:

[image]

I have tried adding my own style to combat this:

```
.radioButtonList
{
    border-collapse:separate;
}
```

But that seems to have no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override Bootstrap, which is probably more specific, or further down in the cascade. Just add `!important`

Like so:

```
.radioButtonList {
    border-collapse:separate !important;
}
```

Comment: Works, forgot to refresh -_-'

Comment: @Milo Silly Milo :) Good stuff.